# How to connect app on Nuxt3 with firebase?

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, nuxt3, vuefire

I am installed all dependencies for connect my app on Nuxt3 with firebase, using oficial docs vuefire  https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/getting-started.html#configuration and setup nuxt.config.ts :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      charset: "utf-8",
      viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: "ru"
      },
      link: []
    }
  },
  typescript: {
    strict: true
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxt/image-edge',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    'nuxt-icon',
    'nuxt-vuefire',
  ],
  vuefire: {
    config: {
      apiKey: '...',
      authDomain: '...',
      projectId: '...',
      appId: '...',
    },
  },
  css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss'],
})
```

But i am gived a error message when using "npm run dev":

Error while requiring module nuxt-vuefire: Error: Cannot find module 'D:/Develop/SmartGYM/nuxt-vuefire'                                                      17:10:31

I clean cache npm , but this didnt help

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-28094923.e859bba",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.2",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.9.0",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.16.3",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.33.1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.9.0",
    "mande": "^2.0.6",
    "pinia": "^2.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.1",
    "vuefire": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vue": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, i gived a error message in my nuxt.config.ts  - Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuefire' does not exist in type 'InputConfig<NuxtConfig, ConfigLayerMeta>'.ts(2345)

Comment: All dependencies should be in devDependencies in Nuxt 3. Also try removing @firebase/app-types, @nuxt/types and @nuxtjs/composition-api. You also seemed to have missed adding nuxt-vuefire

Comment: @AlexanderDerevkov did you get any solution?